# Python Test Assert

Tags: python, pandas, unit-testing, assert

### Writing a test cases to QA a excel file

I am creating this test case to make sure there is no " NA, nan, None, N/A, empty"

Here is the input File image:

[Dataset Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6tBc.png)

when I run the code below Column A is passing the test, even-though there is an empty row in line 3.

```
import unittest
import pandas as pd

class TestC(unittest.TestCase):
      def testRowWithNan(self):
          df= pd.read_excel('abc\test.xlsx','sheet1')
          tab = df['Emp_Name']
          self.assertIsNotNone(tab)
if__name__ == '__main__':
     unittest.main()
```

Please let me know if any one solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am not that familiar with pandas but `df['Emp_Name']` should return list of all the names, you need to check every name in that column. So you need to create a loop like so:

```py
not_want = ["NA", "nan", None, "N/A", "empty"]
for name in df["Emp_name"]:
    # Checking if any of the words that we do not want is in the name
    # If we have the word that we do not want in the name any() will turn true and
    # the test will fail.
    assert any(word in name for word in not_want) is False
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used unittest library so can't exactly say how you would test via unittest, but I'd simply test like this:

```
names = df.Emp_Name.values
assert not np.isnan(names).any()
```